# What is the difference between these two pytorch tensors?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two list of tensors where one can be concatenated with `torch.cat()` while the last one can not be concatenated with `torch.cat()`. Therefore I wanted to know what is the difference between these two tensors and how we can concatenate the last one. I see that the tensor `value.item()` has a square brackets while in the last one there is no bracket surrounding the `value.item()`

[image]

```
def update(self, episode: dict, gamma: float) -> dict:
"""
Updates the policy and value networks and returns 
a dictionary with the overall loss and the loss at 
each step for the policy and value nets.

Args:
    episode: a dicitonary with states, actions, rewards, and log probabilites
    gamma: the discount factor

Returns:
    a dicitonary with the loss at each state and the overall loss for the policy and value nets.
"""   
# use this list to keep track of the loss terms at the individual steps
policy_losses = []
value_losses = []

# TODO compute returns by calling `compute_returns(rewards, gamma)`, as it
# already includes the return standardization
# YOUR CODE HERE
#raise NotImplementedError()

states, actions, rewards, log_probs, values = episode.values()
returns = compute_returns(rewards, gamma=gamma)
returns = torch.tensor(returns)

for a_log_prob, state_value, R in zip(log_probs, values, returns):
    policy_losses.append(-1 * a_log_prob * (R - state_value.item()))
    value_losses.append(torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(state_value, torch.tensor([R]), reduction='mean'))
print('p',policy_losses)
print('v',value_losses)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# --- the code below does not need to be changed ------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# this resets the gradients on all involved weight tensors
self.policy_optimizer.zero_grad()
self.value_optimizer.zero_grad()

# this concatenates all individual policy loss terms
policy_losses = torch.cat(policy_losses)
print(policy_losses)
value_losses = torch.cat(value_losses)
    
# here we sum all policy losses up. this implements the gradient accumulation
# "theta = theta + ..." from the pseudo code, where it says
# "loop for each step of the episode ..." in one neat line.
policy_loss = policy_losses.sum()
value_loss = value_losses.sum()

# this computes the gradient of the loss wrt all involved weight tensors
policy_loss.backward()
value_loss.backward()
# this updates the weight tensors with the update rule of the optimizer
# we're not using vanilla SGD here, but rather the Adam update rule,
# as it converges much, much faster
self.policy_optimizer.step()
self.value_optimizer.step()
    
# finally, we'll return the policy_loss and value_loss for visualization purposes later on
return dict(
    policy_loss=policy_loss.item(),
    value_loss=value_loss.item(),
    policy_losses=policy_losses,
    value_losses=value_losses
)
```

[image]

Comment: They have different shapes. The error message clearly tells that each value is a 0-dim tensor which can’t be concatenated. Try comparing the shape of each element of `policy_losses` and `value_losses`.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in the distinction between a zero-dimensional tensor with a single value (pytorch would list its shape as `torch.Size([])`) versus a one-dimensional tensor with a single value (pytorch would list its shape as `torch.Size([1])`.

The former cannot be concatenated (as there is no dimension along which to concatenate) while the latter can. You can easily convert the former to the latter by:

```
dim1 = dim0.unsqueeze(0)
```

Alternatively, you can use `torch.stack` which "concatenates" tensors along a new dimension.